# Shared methods within angular controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand how one may have shared methods across various controllers. For example http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/sharing-code-between-controllers-using-services.html. However, I was wondering whether it is possible to share methods without necessarily having to declare them within every controller.

So instead of ...

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.factory("UserService", function() {
  var users = ["Peter", "Daniel", "Nina"];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return users;
    },
    first: function() {
      return users[0];
    }
  };
});

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, UserService) {
  $scope.users = UserService.all();
});

app.controller("AnotherCtrl", function($scope, UserService) {
  $scope.firstUser = UserService.first();
});
```

... would it be possible to do without the statements `$scope.users = UserService.all();` and `$scope.users = UserService.all();`, but still have them available from the views? Otherwise, if I have ten different controllers, I would have to repeat the same statements ten times.

Comment: A view Looks for the data in controller so in hierarchy it will look for its controller to get the data if it gets data in its controller it displays else it looks for data in parent controller, so for you if its global kind on thing which will be called just once assign it to rootscope in run however rootscope is not preferred when following a strict angular practice

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you could simply use another controller that will be the only one using your service. Then, wrap any element that needs to access that data within one that uses your new controller.

For instance, considering the following controller being created:

```
app.controller("UsersCtrl", function(UserService) {
  return {
    all: UserService.all(),
    first: UserService.first()
  };
});
```

You could inject its data (your users) and any method to interact with your service in any scope by making a simple addition to your html.

Where you would previously had:

```
<div ng-controller="AnotherCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{firstUser}}</p>
</div>
```

... you could now use:

```
<div ng-controller="UsersCtrl as users">
  <div ng-controller="AnotherCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{users.first}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And both your `MyCtrl` and `AnotherCtrl` won't even have to be injected the `UsersService`. They could be simply rewritten as follows:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  // ...
});

app.controller("AnotherCtrl", function($scope) {
  // ...
});
```

---

Here's a more complete example html content that re-uses the new `UsersCtrl` to provide data utilized by your other controllers:

```
<div ng-controller="UsersCtrl as users">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Users' contact</h1>
    <p ng-repeat="user in users.all">
      <a href="mailto:{{::getEmailFor(user)}}">{{::getEmailFor(user)}}</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="AnotherCtrl">
    <h1>Users' personal information</h1>
    <p ng-repeat="user in users.all" ng-init="colour = getFavouriteColourFor(user)">
      {{user}}'s favourite colour: <span class="text-{{colour}}">{{colour}}</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In addition, here is a simple [live working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3dghpq5/), based on your sample data.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help! If that works for you, don't hesitate to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) `:)`.